# How to write PySpark dataframe to DynamoDB table?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

How to write PySpark dataframe to DynamoDB table? Did not find much info on this. As per my requirement, i have to write PySpark dataframe to Dynamo db table. Overall i need to read/write to dynamo from my PySpark code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would like to know whether PySpark supports Dynamodb ? As per my knowledge python supports. Any body tried with Pyspark.

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector (this is for scala).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ram, there's no way to do that directly from pyspark. If you have pipeline software running it can be done in a series of steps. Here is how it can be done:

1. Create a temporary hive table like

   `CREATE TABLE TEMP(
           column1 type,
           column2 type...)
    STORED AS ORC;`
2. Run your pySpark job and write your data to it

   `dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
   spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE temp SELECT * FROM df")`
3. Create the dynamo connector table

   `CREATE TABLE TEMPTODYNAMO(
       column1 type,
       column2 type...)
   STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
   TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "temp-to-dynamo",
   "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "column1:column1,column2:column2...";`
4. Overwrite that table with your temp table

   `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TEMPTODYNAMO SELECT * FROM TEMP;`

More info here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html

Comment: Good answer mate!

Comment: Thats great ! Thanks for the timely advice.

Comment: This approach will not work for maps/list/boolean/null data types in dynamodb. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.ExternalTableForDDB.html#EMRforDynamoDB.ExternalTableForDDB.DataTypes

Comment: is the above pipeline robust enough to handle 4 million inserts?

Comment: It does work for lists. also yes we were writing 10s of millions of inserts weekly

Comment: great! Just an add-on question, my data consists of complex datatype like the dictionary. Does this support complex datatypes? Also, you have used ORC for creating a temp table. Any specific reason?

Comment: No reason to use that specific serialization format. I was using Dynamo's list datatype but it looks like they have document (json-like) fields. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

Comment: Just curious, why can't we define a UDF that uses boto to write content to Dynamo DB?

Comment: Adding some info that might be helpful: don't break the line in `"dynamodb.column.mapping"`. I had 54 columns to map and decided to break the line so the code was easier to read. Even though I was able to create the table (no error was thrown) it didn't load the data. So I droped the table, recreated it with the `"dynamodb.column.mapping"` in a single line, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [spark-dynamodb](https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb).

From their repo:

```
# Load a DataFrame from a Dynamo table. Only incurs the cost of a single scan for schema inference.
dynamoDf = spark.read.option("tableName", "SomeTableName") \
                     .format("dynamodb") \
                     .load() # <-- DataFrame of Row objects with inferred schema.

# Scan the table for the first 100 items (the order is arbitrary) and print them.
dynamoDf.show(100)

# write to some other table overwriting existing item with same keys
dynamoDf.write.option("tableName", "SomeOtherTable") \
              .format("dynamodb") \
              .save()
```

Answer (score 1):

This AWS blog explains how to create a unique key, partition and write S3 data (csv) to DynamoDB table using AWS Glue.

[How realtor.com® maximized data upload from Amazon S3 into Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-realtor-com-maximized-data-upload-from-amazon-s3-into-amazon-dynamodb/)

Answer (score 0):

we are saving pyspark output to parquet on S3, then using awswrangler layer in lambda to read the parquet data to pandas frame and wrangler.dynamodb.put_df to write the whole dataframe to the dynamoDB table. Pretty decent scaling with lambda concurrency and s3 event trigger