# pyspark code to copy dynamodb table to hive issues: Operation not allowed

Tags: hive, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I am trying to create an external hive table from Dynamodb on aws emr, using pyspark code. The query works fine when I execute it on the hive prompt, but fails when I execute it as a pyspark job. The code is as below:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sql('use ash_data')

spark.sql(
    """
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dummyTable
        (item MAP<STRING, STRING>)
    STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
    TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "testdynamodb")
    """
)
```

It keeps giving me the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u'\nOperation not allowed: STORED BY(line 4, pos 4)\n\n== SQL ==\n\n    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dummyTable\n        (item MAP<STRING, STRING>)\n    STORED BY \'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler\'\n----^^^\n    TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "testdynamodb")\n    \n'
```

Do we need to setup any permissions or roles to make this work ? Has anybody found any solution for this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't supported by Spark SQL:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19661

You have to:

- run the command to create the table using `hive`
- write from to a different hive table in Spark with similar schema
- run a command in hive to write your spark-generated data to the dynamodb-backed external table

See this answer to a similar question for more details:

[How to write PySpark dataframe to DynamoDB table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044026/how-to-write-pyspark-dataframe-to-dynamodb-table/53053506)