# Pyspark dataframe or parquet file to DynamoDB

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I want to put a pyspark dataframe or a parquet file into a DynamoDB table

The pyspark dataframe that I have has 30MM rows and 20 columns

**Solution 1: using boto3, pandas and Batch writing ([Amazon DynamoDB](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html))**

With this I read the parquet file and pass it to pandas, then I put row by row into the DynamoDB table, but this is taking too long, is very very slow

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='name')

table = dynamodb.Table('DynamoDB_table_name')
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for index, row in pandas_dataframe.iterrows():
      batch.put_item(
          Item = {
              'column_name_DynamoDB_table': int(row['column_name_in_pandas_dataframe']),
              ...
          }
      )
```

**Solution 2: using boto3, pyspark and SQL ([how-to-write-pyspark-dataframe-to-dynamodb-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044026/how-to-write-pyspark-dataframe-to-dynamodb-table))**

Here I keep getting an error in the step 3 describe in the solution, a **ParseException** error, I check in the amazon documentation and I see the code is correct ([EMR_Hive_Commands.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html)), maybe it is not SQL code and that is my error, but if it's not, I don't know which language is

```
-- Step 1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP;
CREATE TABLE TEMP(
        column_name_DynamoDB_table type,
        ... )
 STORED AS ORC; 

--step 2.1
pyspark_dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("df")


--step 2.2
INSERT INTO temp
    SELECT *
    FROM df


--step 3
CREATE TABLE TEMPTODYNAMO(
        column_name_DynamoDB_table type,
        ... )
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ( "dynamodb.table.name" ="temp-to-dynamo" , 
                "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "col1:column_name_DynamoDB_table,...");
```

the error I keep getting:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
Operation not allowed: STORED BY(line 22, pos 0)

== SQL ==
CREATE TABLE TEMPTODYNAMO(
        column_name_DynamoDB_table type,
        ...  )
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
^^^
TBLPROPERTIES ( "dynamodb.table.name" ="temp-to-dynamo" , 
                "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "col1:column_name_DynamoDB_table,...")
```

**Solution 3: using boto3, pyspark and com.audienceproject ([Spark+DynamoDB](https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb))**

I did not understand what to put in the code, the python code show in the page is:

```
# Python
# Load a DataFrame from a Dynamo table. Only incurs the cost of a single scan for schema inference.
dynamoDf = spark.read.option("tableName", "SomeTableName") \
                     .format("dynamodb") \
                     .load() # <-- DataFrame of Row objects with inferred schema.

# Scan the table for the first 100 items (the order is arbitrary) and print them.
dynamoDf.show(100)

# write to some other table overwriting existing item with same keys
dynamoDf.write.option("tableName", "SomeOtherTable") \
              .format("dynamodb") \
              .save()
```

But I really did not get where to put the name of my DynamoDB table and my pyspark dataframe

Update: I tried

```
pysaprk_dataframe.write.option("tableName", "name_DynamoDB_table") \
                .format("dynamodb") \
                .save()
```

And got this error:

```
AnalysisException: TableProvider implementation dynamodb cannot be written with ErrorIfExists mode, please use Append or Overwrite modes instead
```

Regards

Comment: I tried "Solution 2" and it worked fine. I also got the `ParseException` error when tried to run query "step 3" from Spark SQL. Instead, I have to run query "step 3" from Hive CLI and that solved the problems. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56078788/10152848).

Answer (score 1):

Have tried Solution # 3, with the below code snippet and got it working

code change was to add the mode('append')

```
dynamoDf.write.mode('append').option("tableName","db_dev_users_v2") \
              .option("region",region) \
              .format("dynamodb") \
              .save()
```