# How to write large Pyspark DataFrame to DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I have pyspark data frame with 3+ million of records and it's necessary to write it to Dynamo db. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write PySpark dataframe to DynamoDB table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044026/how-to-write-pyspark-dataframe-to-dynamodb-table)

Comment: The question is how to do it from python code and for huge data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this using python then you can do this as:

- save the spark df with sufficient number of files i.e. if file size is 5 GB, generate 50 files of 100 mb.
- Now write python code with multiprocessing where your process pool will be equal to the number of CPU's available.
- Write the files using dynamodb's boto3 batch_writer and process all files parallely.

For this you can use either glue python shell or create your own container and launch it on fargate.